# Plot Graphics in a loop and combine them in the end in one graphic done all over variables

Tags: plotting, graphics

So I have an xls file with 5 Collums and a few thusand rows. 
Now i want to get only 3 of the collums plot them over the number of rows and then put them in one single graphic. But it should be variable so if I have a diffrent table with more, less collums or want to choose diffrent collums I just have to adopt some variables

```
i := 2;
j := 1;
t = 3;
testtabele = 
  Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "test.xls"];



Do[Liwind[i + j] = testtabele[[1 ;;, 3 ;;, i + j]], {j, t}] 

Do[Liwind[i + j] = Liwind[i + j]/1000, {j, t}]

Do[Print[ListLinePlot[Liwind[i + j]]], {j, t}]
(* Prints for every List one graph*)
```

Here are diffrent things I tried.

```
Do[
   Print[
      ListLinePlot[
        {Liwind[i + j], Liwind[i + j],Liwind[i + j]}
        ]
     ],{j, 3}
  ]

Do[p[i+j]=[ListLinePlot[Liwind[i+j]]],{j,t}]

Show[p[i + j], p[i + j + 1], p[i + j + 2]]
```

Hope someone can Help me with that

Comment: Just a helpful hint: you don't need `Print` if you use `Table` instead of `Do`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass your data to [`ListLinePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html) in the layout it expects, in this case it's the third form shown in the docs: `ListLinePlot[{data1,data2,...}]`.

Each of the datai will correspond to a column you wish to plot, either just the y-values:

> data1 = {y1,y2,y3,...}

or both x and y values:

> data1 = {{x1,y1},{x2,y2},{x3,x3},...}

So if I generate some mock data with 5 columns and 221 rows:

```
mockData = Table[Sin[a x], {x, 0., 22, 0.1}, {a, 1, 5}];
```

The following will plot just columns 1, 3, and 4:

```
cols={1,3,4};
ListLinePlot[Transpose[mockData[[;; , cols]]], 
 PlotLegends -> ("Column " <> ToString[#] & /@ cols)]
```

[image]

Have a look at what `mockData[[;; , cols]]` returns and see why the`Transpose` helps.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer
if i understand it correct my loop gives me the diffrent data1, data2, ... only with y cordinates But if i try then ListLinePlot[{data1,data2,...}] i only get back that datai are not list of numbers or pairs your code looks intteresing but after i copied to a new notebook it doesn't showed me anything is there a problem or diffrent in the version 11?

Comment: I forgot to specify `cols`, which should be `{1,3,4}` in my example. I've edited it in.